# How can I proceed with the else statement after reaching the last record of the table?

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, while-loop, limit

1. i have a flag table
2. What I want to do is: after the table query reaches the last record, it then performs the else statement

   ```
   while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
   if (++$counter == $numResults) {
       $sql1 = "UPDATE QueueP1 SET STATUS = '1' WHERE STATUS ='0' LIMIT 1";
       $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
       echo "Now processing No ".$row['now']."<Br>";       
       }
    else{
       echo "<p class='lead'><em>No more transactions left.</em></p>";
   ```

   }
   }

Comment: when it reaches the last record, it still performs the if statement instead of the else statement

Comment: preceding code       $sql = "SELECT (COUNT(1)+1) AS 'now' FROM QueueP1 WHERE STATUS = '1'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QueueP1";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
$counter = 0

Comment: (1) The *preceding* query always returns one row, so there is no point for a loop. (2) `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` usually does nto make sense (your statement updates an arbitrary rows out of the matching onces) (3) If you want things to run in sequence, don't use an `if/else` construct, just put the commands in sequence. Corolary: you might need to give us a better description of what you are trying to achieve, so one can rework this piece of code.

Comment: 1. For every press of the button, it would flag one record as finished until it flags all the records. Im doing a queuing system that calls out every single row each time a button is pressed

Comment: The code doesn't make much sense but shouldn't you check for ``` ++$counter <= $numResults ``` ? I might be missing what you are trying to do.

Comment: i just tried it from what Ive researched. But, what condition I am trying to figure out how to code is - while counter is less than or equal to number of rows, it will perform something and if else - it will do another thing. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Here there's no use of mentioning a query in while loop.I think what you want is this

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE QueueP1 SET STATUS = '1' WHERE STATUS ='0' LIMIT 1";
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
if (++$counter == $numResults) {  
 echo "Now processing No ".$row['now']."<Br>";       
    }
}
echo "<p class='lead'><em>No more transactions left.</em></p>";
```

Comment: it didnt work @kunal Raut I have a sample table with 8 records but it still loops to the if statement after the 8th cycle

Comment: I think the condition statement is not serving my purpose

Comment: Yes i think so too.

Comment: can you rewrite it